# Code consisting hasNextInt argurment Error

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program which prompts the user to enter an input and display the output only if the input was an Integer

1. If the user enters a non-integer value, the program will loop
   through until it gets an integer value
2. If input is an integer, the program will display its value

My desired output will be something like this:

1. Enter a number : a
2. Invalid input. Please enter an Integer
3. Enter a number : b
4. Invalid input. Please enter an Integer
5. Enter a number : 66
6. Your value is 66

   System.out.println("Enter a number");

   ```
   boolean hasNextInt = input.hasNextInt();
   int value =0;

   while(!hasNextInt){
       System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter an Integer");
        value = input.nextInt();
   }

   System.out.println("Your value is "+value);
   ```

Any sort of help will be appreciated! :)

Comment: You're not updating `hasNextInt`. You should put `while (!input.hasNextInt())`

Comment: i changed it from hasNextInt to while(!input.hasNextInt()) but it still shows error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Comment: You're calling `nextInt` even though `input` doesn't have a next integer. There's a logic error.

Comment: Bear with me as i am very new to programming. Could you please explain what has to be done? I do not really get what you meant haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it now, you will try to read an int when your `Scanner` *doesn't* have an int. You should instead try this:

```
int value = 0;
while(!input.hasNextInt()){
    System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter an Integer");
    input.next();
}
value = input.nextInt();
```

This way, you're reading an int *afterwards*, when input does have an int.

Comment: Doesn't the loop not end with ur code? it will print the String infinitely if user inputs a non-integer value.

Comment: Thank youuu sooo much! It worked! Just to clarify, does.hasnextInt() have to come before .nextInt() in all situations? I dont really get the logic.

Comment: Noted. Also, what does input.next() mean in the code above. It's a little weird for me because I am used to seeing a declaration for input.next. For eg: int value= input.nextInt()

Comment: yeah it worked. TYSM! but what do u mean by accepting ur answer, I am new to stack overflow too

Comment: Got it. TYSM once again